# E-Book creation using MSWord (in HTML), how to include references

Tags: html, epub

I'm converting a previously published book to an e-book, which will be self-published on Amazon. Things are going well, I'm using several online guides to correct stylistic errors and the like. One issue has arisen: The book is on nutritional science, and the print version contains over 200 references (included in the text as superscript). What are my options as far as hyperlinking them to the ebook text? I would prefer the references to appear as hyperlinked superscript, which could pull up a popup box when selected (much like the dictionary function on most e-books). Is this possible? Or should I use the bookmark/hyperlink functions within word and put references in their own end section?

Answer (score 0):

Popup functionality for footnotes is not a built-in part of the epub spec. Apple has implemented it for iBooks as long as you mark the code up properly with epub:type declarations. You'll want the superscripted number set up like `<a href=#note24 epub:type="noteref">24</a>` and the corresponding footnote to be `<p id="note24" epub:type="footnote">Content goes here</p>`

The important bits are the epub:type declarations. Note that use of epub:type implies that you're using epub 3.0 rather than epub 2.0.1. If you're just using MS Word,then you're out of luck on that score.

Further details can be found on Liz Castro's blog: http://www.pigsgourdsandwikis.com/2012/05/creating-pop-up-footnotes-in-epub-3-and.html